# How can I create a form to validate inputs and perform a multiplication?

Tags: javascript

I was absent during class and my book isn't very useful. **I haven't learned how to make a button yet** and do not know how to complete this assignment. Any help is appreciated. Please note: I am a beginner and this is for an intro class so keep it simple please!

1. Two input boxes, one to accept the price of an item and another to accept the number of items to order.
2. One button to calculate the total.
3. Use an alert message to tell them the total price or that the input data is invalid.
4. Use a function to validate that the price and number of items are numeric.
5. Once the data is valid, use a function that accepts two arguments, one for price and one 
   for the number of items, to calculate the total and then displays the total price.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Lab 8b: Stephanie Hussar</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Input

        itemPrice = Number(prompt("Please enter the price of the item."));
        itemQuantity = Number(prompt("Please enter the quantity of the items"));
        total = itemPrice * itemQuantity


    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Is this an online course? You've posted some in the past - perhaps ask the lecturer to put notes online?

Comment: she records the class (the computer screen shot) but it's very useless! she confuses herself and the class..

Comment: I mostly need help setting up the button and i'll be good to go

Comment: This should get you started (you'll need to work out how to validate): http://jsfiddle.net/gLbBy/ (Hint - try clicking without entering anything.)

Comment: See example below as well - Jared - can you update with anything below for that js fiddle - nice one.

Comment: Stephanie, you do realize you should not publicly say "she confuses herself and the class" about your teacher? She would not be too thrilled if she googles your name and finds this question, would she?

Comment: @StephanieKay All the steps have been added to my explanation! Please let me know if there's something you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like your current implementaton doesn't match the assignment. It seems to me like you need to input fields and then one button, so let's start with that:

Input Field:
`<input type="text" name="item_price" id="id_item_price" />`

This creates a text input with the form name `item price` and id of `id_item_price`.

Button:
`<input type="button" name="item_submit" id="id_item_submit" value="Calculate!" />`

This creates a button that allows us to submit. I'm keeping it a `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` because I'm handling this in JavaScript and don't want to submit the form to another web page.

Putting these together, we have our HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>My JavaScript</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // TO DO: The Script!
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <b>Enter the Item Price:</b><br />
    <input type="text" name="item_price" id="id_item_price" />

    <br /><br />

    <b>Enter the Item Quantity:</b><br />
    <input type="text" name="item_quantity" id="id_item_quantity" />

    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="item_submit" id="id_item_submit" value="Calculate!" />

</body>

</html>
```

**Adding in the calculations**

Now that we have the HTML we have to look at the script. There's a few concepts here to be aware of.

*Executing code when a button is pressed*

HTML allows us to specify what happens when an element is interacted with. One such tool is called `onclick`. By changing our button HTML to the following, we can call a JavaScript function `doCalculations()` whenever the button is clicked!

`<input type="button" name="item_submit" id="id_item_submit" value="Calculate" onclick="doCalculations()" />`

Now that we've got that done, let's look at what doCalculations() looks like.

**"Do Calculations"**

We haven't gotten around to validation yet, but to make sure everything is working we want to check out a few concepts.

First is getting the actual text field from the HTML document. Remember earlier how we said that the Item Price would have an ID of `id_item_price`? Well turns out that will help us access it now with this piece of code:

`itemPrice = document.getElementById( 'id_item_price' );`

This creates a new variable called `itemPrice`. We then use JavaScript's `getElementById()` function to grab a reference to that specific text field. Using the same method we can get the quantity (and, if we wanted to, even the button!):

`itemQuantity = document.getElementById( 'id_item_quantity' );`

Now that we have the form fields, we need to actually do the calculation. By hold on: We have a slight problem. We stored a reference to those input fields in a variable, but we don't have the actual value - only the field. No worries, JavaScript makes that easy for us:

`<Field>.value` Gives us the value of a specific field. So, putting this together we can get itemPrice's value by doing `itemPrice.value`.

Now that we can grab the values, let's do the actual calculation and store it in a variable called `myTotal`:

`myTotal = itemPrice.value * itemQuantity.value;`

Now all that's left in doCalculations is to output the result. You know how to do that! You're already a pro:

`alert( "The total cost is: " + myTotal + "!" );`.

But oh snap! What if someone types in "apples" instead of a number in one of those fields. Looks like we've got to validate.

**VALIDATION**

This one is a little bit tricky, so stay with me. We need to first create a function to validate our inputs. For this we will use two JavaScript functions. If you don't understand my explanations here, please be sure to look them up online so you can fully comprehend.

`isNan( myNumber )` will return true if JavaScript found a NaN value for the myNumber arguement.

`parseFloat( myNumber )` will return a number if JavaScript was able to turn that entry value into a floating point number. It will return NaN if it couldn't.

`isFinite` will return true if a number is a finite, legal number. False otherwise.

Combining these we can check to see if the number entered is an actual number:

```
function verifyNumber( myInput ){
            if( !isNaN( parseFloat( myInput.value ) ) && isFinite( myInput.value ) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

*ProTip:* Recall that `&&` is a logical AND. It will return true if and only if both results of both functions are true. It will return false otherwise.

So now let's just pop this into our doCalculations example:

```
function doCalculations(){
            itemPrice = document.getElementById( 'id_item_price' );
            itemQuantity = document.getElementById( 'id_item_quantity' );

            // Add in the validations:
            if( !verifyNumber( itemPrice ) || !verifyNumber( itemQuantity ) ){
                alert( "One or both of your numbers is incorrect! Please enter a real number." );
                return false;
            }

            myTotal = itemPrice.value * itemQuantity.value;
            alert( "The total cost is: " + myTotal + "!" );
        }
```

**Wrapping it all up, here is our final code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>My JavaScript</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Function: Verify that the input is an item number
        function verifyNumber( myInput ){
            if( !isNaN( parseFloat( myInput.value ) ) && isFinite( myInput.value ) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        function doCalculations(){
            itemPrice = document.getElementById( 'id_item_price' );
            itemQuantity = document.getElementById( 'id_item_quantity' );

            // Add in the validations:
            if( !verifyNumber( itemPrice ) || !verifyNumber( itemQuantity ) ){
                alert( "One or both of your numbers is incorrect! Please enter a real number." );
                return false;
            }

            myTotal = itemPrice.value * itemQuantity.value;
            alert( "The total cost is: " + myTotal + "!" );
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <b>Enter the Item Price:</b><br />
    <input type="text" name="item_price" id="id_item_price" />

    <br /><br />

    <b>Enter the Item Quantity:</b><br />
    <input type="text" name="item_quantity" id="id_item_quantity" />

    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="item_submit" id="id_item_submit" value="Calculate" onclick="doCalculations()" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hope this helps, @StephanieKay! Feel free to run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/U64wX/

Comment: thank you! this is more up to par with the level i'm at and easy to understand!

Comment: one more question, for this one http://jsfiddle.net/U64wX/1/. how would i verify the user input?

Comment: @StephanieKay It's already in that example, give the page a refresh if you can't see it. It's in the `verifyNumber` function or the "VALIDATION" section above. Please let me know if it isn't clear!

Comment: it's a completely different JavaScript code for a different assignment!

Comment: Whoops! Disregard the comment I deleted, I didn't see your jsfiddle link. It would be very difficult for me to post the explanation here, due to the character limit. Would you mind opening up a new question? That way I can do a similar walk through.

Comment: in this case the user is inputing months in string form. she just said in the video to validate the user input. she wasn't specific to what or how. i guess how do you validate text?

Comment: Well my guess here is she wants you to validate that the month they're entering is correct. So, for example, after they enter month 0 (January) you would compare the two strings. In example: `if( "January" != monthArray[0] ) alert( "Wrong month!" );`. The best way to do this would be to save an array of the valid answers (i.e: `correctMonths = { "January, "February", ....`) and then validating against those (i.e: `if( correctMonths[i] != monthArray[i] ) alert( "Wrong month!" );`).

Comment: ok, thank! i guess i will just leave as is since she was so vague!

Comment: if you're bored, here's my next one! i don't have my code up yet though! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560538/please-help-finish-this-javascript-assignment

Answer (score 1):

1. Two Input Boxes ( a ) for price and ( b ) for quantity

`Price: <input name="price" id="price" value="" /><br />`

`Quantity: <input name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" />`

1. One button to calculate the total

`Price: <input name="price" id="price" value="" /><br />`

`Quantity: <input name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" /><br />`

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Total" id="get-total" />`

1. Use an alert message to tell them the total price or that the input data is invalid.
   i) Assume we need a function

> ```
> function calculate_total (price, quantity) {
>
>   var valid = false;
>   var total = 0;
>   var the_price = 0;
>   var the_quantity = 0;
>
>   // what constitutes a valid price?
>   if(price && 0 < parseFloat(price)) { // perhaps?
>    the_price = parseFloat(price);
>   }
>   if(quantity && 0 < parseInt(quantity)) { // perhaps?
>    the_quantity = parseInt(quantity);
>   }
>
>   if(the_price > 0 && the_quantity > 0) {
>    valid = true; // yay! we can continue :)
>    // do any other things you want to do here
>   }
>
>   if(true === valid) {
>    total = the_price * the_quantity;
>   }
>
>   return total;
>
> }
> ```

ii) Okay so now we have a function, what do we do with it? - Let's call it when we click the submit button, so that it calculates it then

```
document.getElementById('get-total').onclick = function() {
 var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
 var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

 alert(calculate_total(price,quantity)); // this alerts for (3)

 return false; // stop the form being submitted
};
```

4) this is done by the above and so is 5 now

Put it together:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Lab 8b: Stephanie Hussar</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p>
    Price: <input name="price" id="price" value="" /><br />
    Quantity: <input name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Total" id="get-total" />
   </p>
   <script>
    // function to calculate the total from the price and quantity
    // and do basic (very very basic) validation on inputs
    function calculate_total (price, quantity) {
     var valid = false;
     var total = 0;
     var the_price = 0;
     var the_quantity = 0;

     // what constitutes a valid price?
     if(price && 0 < parseFloat(price)) { // perhaps?
      the_price = parseFloat(price);
     }
     if(quantity && 0 < parseInt(quantity)) { // perhaps?
      the_quantity = parseInt(quantity);
     }

     if(the_price > 0 && the_quantity > 0) {
      valid = true; // yay! we can continue :)
      // do any other things you want to do here
     }

     if(true === valid) {
      total = the_price * the_quantity;
     }

     return total;
    }

    // add click event to the button
    document.getElementById('get-total').onclick = function() {
     var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
     var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

     alert(calculate_total(price,quantity)); // this alerts for (3)

     return false; // stop the form being submitted
    };
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to make onclick lowercase instead of onClick, try with lowercase 'onlick' instead of mixed 'onClick' - I've updated my example to fix that - that should work for you.

Comment: ok, thanks! Oh boy my teacher is going know I'm not this advanced!

Comment: Well, you don't need to copy/paste ;) but if it helps you to understand it, then please use as a reference.  I'd hope you'd use it for understanding only  and roll your own :)

Comment: oh, of course not! I use it as demo code to learn from, I wouldnt copy and pass it as my own. We just haven't learned anything this advanced. I redid the code the way she wanted and the way I understand better, but this certaintly helped as a reference/demo code! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Me to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Lab 8b: Stephanie Hussar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function isValid() {
                var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
                var items = document.getElementById('items').value;
                if (items=="" || price=="") {
                    alert('Price and quantity is required!');
                }else if (isNaN(price) || isNaN(items)) {
                    alert('Numbers only!');
                }else{
                    calculate(price, items);
                }
            }

            function calculate(price, item) {
                 var result = document.createTextNode('The total is: '+price*item);
                 var form = document.getElementById('buy');
                 form.appendChild(result);
            }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="buy">
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input id="price" />
        <br />
        <label for="items">Quantity:</label>
        <input id="items" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="isValid();"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MxZSW/1/)

```
​
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution to simple problem:

```
<input id=price type=text>
<input id=quantity type=text>
<input id=but type=button value=calculate onclick="document.getElementById('output').value=document.getElementById('price').value*document.getElementById('quantity').value">
<br><input id=output type=text>
```

Comment: This one doesn't do any validation, though, and does not match the requirements set by her instructor (prompting, alert with results, etc.).